# Use of ES6 Default Function Parameter Value Spec in Lightning (Aura) Components

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, es6

Whilst doing some cleanup of some Aura Components for Summer 16, I was creating a JS function in my helper. I had wanted to add some default values to that function using the new [ES6 Default Parameter Value Spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters). Like so:

```
myFunction = function (param1 = "this", param2 = "that"){
  ...
}
```

Meaning that if I invoked this like

```
helper.myFunction();
> param1 = "this"
> param2 = "that"

helper.myFunction("what is");
> param1 = "what is"
> param2 = "that"
```

No luck. I get an error when I attempt to save the component on the server as such:

> ERROR: 0Ad240000008RPA: org.auraframework.util.json.JsonStreamReader$JsonStreamParseException: Expected ',' or ')' [64, 30]: '='

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just bumped in this issue and I would like to share my findings.

The following syntax is still not supported (you'll get a `JsonStreamParseException`):

```
myFunction = function (param1 = "this", param2 = "that")
```

However, if you write it this way (without spaces around the equal signs), the default parameter values work fine:

```
myFunction = function (param1="this", param2="that")
```

I hope this will help someone.

Comment: LOL! Because whitespace doesn't matter in JS, right? Good job ferreting out how to get this to work!

Comment: For the record, according to the Lightning team this is a Closure compiler bug. This ES6 syntax is not officially supported in Lightning so it could go away in the future if the compiler is updated.

Comment: The marked answer no longer works in 20 regrettably.

Answer (score 11):

It turns out Lightning Components are using a version of [closure compiler](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/compressing-javascript) that is incompatible with this syntax currently. So as of Summer 16, certain syntax that is ES6 compliant will not work with Lightning Components.

I found this out through raising an [issue](https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/issues/50) with the aura open source framework [repo](https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura) in github.

> **Note:** this is not an issue in Lightning Web Components

Comment: The problem is even more critical than that. While you are in Debug Mode (Setup>Build>Develop>Lightning Components) and you are working in an ES6 compatible browser (e.g. Chrome supports natively default parameters), then you will not notice any issue because Closure is just not minifying your code. The problem occurs when you turn off the Debug Mode, letting you possibly with many unexpected/undebuggable/etc. errors...